# Reference current data.frame in dplyr flow

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I reference the current data.frame in a dpylr flow? As an example, in

```
library(dplyr)

myresults = tribble(
  ~dataset_name, ~method_group, ~method, ~value,
  'iris',        'other',       'a',     1,
  'wine',        'other',       'b',     2,
  'iris',        'mine',        'c',     3,
  'wine',        'mine',        'd',     4
)

myresults %>%
  mutate(dataset_name='datasets aggregated') %>%
  bind_rows(XXX %>% filter(method=='c') %>% mutate(method_group = 'other'))
```

I would like to row-bind the current data.frame with itself. What do I write instead of the XXX ?

In the function `do()`, [the answer seems to be `.`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/do.html). Even though this is not very elegant and I would prefer not to have to use do, I managed to get the desired result with

```
myresults %>%
  mutate(dataset_name='datasets aggregated') %>%
  do(bind_rows(data.frame(.), data.frame(.) %>% filter(method=='c') %>% mutate(method_group = 'other')))
```

but this is not very nice.

My R version is:

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.4                         
year           2018                        
month          03                          
day            15                          
svn rev        74408                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
nickname       Someone to Lean On
```

Comment: Instead of chaining everything together, why don't you try two separate computations and then bind the results? A short example with desired output will help.

Comment: @aichao: Because the second line with "mutate(dataset_name..." would have to be repeated. Image a more complex scenario. Now, we could alternatively build intermediate data.frames as another alternative, but this will clog the namespace and thus my little window in RStudio which displays all my data.frames. Of course the code above is only a small part of a large project, so things add up.

Comment: @Make42 In general, it is good to provide a small input data set (this one can be very small) and an expected output data set, that should ensure that everyone is on the same page.

Comment: @steveb: Done. Tell if it does not work for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three options that I see:

1. Move the `.` to within `filter`, since it appears to know what to do:

   ```
   myresults %>%
     mutate(dataset_name='datasets aggregated') %>%
     bind_rows(filter(., method=='c') %>% mutate(method_group = 'other'))
   # # A tibble: 5 x 4
   #   dataset_name        method_group method value
   #   <chr>               <chr>        <chr>  <dbl>
   # 1 datasets aggregated other        a          1
   # 2 datasets aggregated other        b          2
   # 3 datasets aggregated mine         c          3
   # 4 datasets aggregated mine         d          4
   # 5 datasets aggregated other        c          3
   ```
2. Use a temporary variable, mid-pipe:

   ```
   z <- myresults %>% mutate(dataset_name='datasets aggregated')
   bind_rows(z, z %>% filter(method=='c') %>% mutate(method_group = 'other'))
   # # A tibble: 5 x 4
   #   dataset_name        method_group method value
   #   <chr>               <chr>        <chr>  <dbl>
   # 1 datasets aggregated other        a          1
   # 2 datasets aggregated other        b          2
   # 3 datasets aggregated mine         c          3
   # 4 datasets aggregated mine         d          4
   # 5 datasets aggregated other        c          3
   ```
3. Similar to your `do` implementation. (You don't need `data.frame(.)`, that's a little redundant, but `do` apparently does not replace instances of the `.` within a nested pipe.)

   ```
   myresults %>%
     mutate(dataset_name='datasets aggregated') %>%
     do({dat <- .; bind_rows(dat, dat %>% filter(method=='c') %>% mutate(method_group = 'other'))})
   # # A tibble: 5 x 4
   #   dataset_name        method_group method value
   #   <chr>               <chr>        <chr>  <dbl>
   # 1 datasets aggregated other        a          1
   # 2 datasets aggregated other        b          2
   # 3 datasets aggregated mine         c          3
   # 4 datasets aggregated mine         d          4
   # 5 datasets aggregated other        c          3
   ```

Comment: I like 1, since it is short and does not produce further data.frames. Regarding 3: If I do not use `data.frame(.)` I get an error that a data.frame is expected not a sequence as the second argument (or something like that).

Comment: Odd that you get an error and I do not. Are you getting that error with the sample data from the question or just from your actual data?

Comment: Also with the sample data that I posted here: "Argument 2 must be a data frame or a named atomic vector, not a fseq/function"

Comment: I'm using `dplyr-0.7.6` on R-3.5.1-x86_64-w64-mingw32, perhaps there's a relevant version difference in either of those.

Comment: Maybe, my dplyr is 0.74. Not sure about my R.

Comment: (`R.version` gives you the R version.) There are [many changes to `dplyr` since 0.7.4](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/NEWS.md), and I don't know if or which of them might be the culprit.

Comment: I added the version to the question post. Me neither, but tonight is not the night for finding out ;-).