# dplyr: access full data frame (including added column) inside filter()

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I'm sure there is a better way to ask this question, and perhaps if I knew it I'd have found an existing answer. The gist is this:

- I'm reading in SQL data with R with NEW, UPDATE, and DELETE rows
- table uniqueness is determined by values in two columns (call them `a` and `b`)
- I want (a) find all combinations of `a` and `b` in which column `c` has a DELETE value, and (b) then remove all rows with one of these `a` and `b` combinations

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  a = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
  b = c(3, 3, 4, 5, 5),
  c = c("new", "delete", "new", "new", "update")
)
```

What I tried, not thinking this through:

```
df %>%
  mutate(filter_key = paste0(a, "_", b)) %>%
  filter(!(filter_key %in% (df %>%
                              filter(c == "delete") %>%
                              pull(filter_key) %>%
                              unique())))
```

The problem is that `filter_key` is not in `df`, so it's not there to pull unique values for. I'm curious if there is a way to refer to it "on the fly"? Some answers led me to think I could perhaps [use `.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52457645/reference-current-data-frame-in-dplyr-flow) or [`.data`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27197617/filter-data-frame-by-character-column-name-in-dplyr), but this didn't work for me (replacing `df` with `.` or `.data`).

The trivial solution is to add it beforehand:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(filter_key = paste0(a, "_", b))
df %>%
  filter(!(filter_key %in% (df %>%
                              filter(c == "delete") %>%
                              pull(filter_key) %>%
                              unique())))
```

---

Alternatively (though this changes the question, so I'll leave it in these "notes"), there's probably a way to just filter directly, but I wasn't sure how to say:

- give me all the combos of `a` and `b` where any row has `c == "delete"`
- remove all rows where `a` and `b` match one of these combos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(both = str_c(a, b)) %>%
  filter(!both %in% (cur_data() %>%
                      filter(c == 'delete') %>%
                      pull(both)))

  a b      c both
1 1 4    new   14
2 2 5    new   25
3 2 5 update   25
```

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't run across that function. Thanks for teaching me something new!

Comment: My question was a form of xy problem. This answers what I started asking, which was how to access the current df, including on-the-fly columns, from within the pipeline. Thank you for that answer!

For others looking for solutions, I think the `anti_join()` question was a cleaner approach to my actual need.

Answer (score 2):

Use an anti-join:

```
df %>% anti_join(filter(., c == "delete"), by = c("a", "b"))
```

giving

```
  a b      c
1 1 4    new
2 2 5    new
3 2 5 update
```

Comment: Never heard of this. Awesome, and appreciate learning something new!